# Angular2 : Iterate to get only array I decide

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic2

I need to iterate over json objects and array and for a specific thing I need return only array with my reviews.

I get and endpoint from my api like this :

```
{total_reviews: 206, average_score: 4.2,…}
average_score
:
4.2
reviews
:
[{meta_id: "259", rating_post_id: "5", rating_user_id: "1", rating_user_name: "christophe",…},…]
total_reviews
:
206
```

And in my angular service, I getting my endpoint like this :

```
getReviewsByPostId(paramsObj) {
    let params = this.util.transformRequest(paramsObj);
    return this.http.get(this.wpApiURL + '/reviews?' + params)
        .map(res => {
            this.reviews = res.json();
            return this.reviews;
        });
}
```

I also have a component :

```
loadReviews(postId) {
    this.wp.getReviewsByPostId({post: postId}).subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.reviews = data;
        },
        error => {}            
    );
}
```

What's the method te return only reviews array in my angular app ? And not total_reviews and average_score

Thank you !

Comment: please use angular tag and not angularjs.. The former is for angular 2 and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly access the "reviews" value from your json response
Im not sure of the exact syntax but try one of the following

```
    res.json().reviews
```

or

```
    res.reviews
```

You could alternatively run a 'foreach' on your JSON response to only take the value of a specific key you require(in your case'reviews')

example:

```
    getReviewsByPostId(paramsObj) {
     let params = this.util.transformRequest(paramsObj);
     return this.http.get(this.wpApiURL + '/reviews?' + params)
     .map(res => {
        this.reviews = res.json();
        angular.forEach(this.reviews,function (key,value){
        if(key==='reviews'){
        //store value in an array or any other data container
        } 
       });
       // return array/dataContainer;
    });
   }
```